# Bytes from Java to Image in Sqlserver

Tags: java, android, asp.net, sql-server

We are sending image from Android mobile in Bytes, through webservice(asmx) we need to store in Sqlserver  as Image Datatype.

I converted it by **cast(@signature as IMAGE)**, but is not reproducing  the image.

The Byte will be somethinsg like **[B@4228ce20**

Suggest a good solution

Thanks in Advance

Bala

Comment: **[B@4228ce20** this seems to be the Byte array's string representation. Not the actual image data..

Comment: This is how we receive from android device, can I convert to image data

Comment: Post your Android device code where you send the image...

Comment: signBytes = (Base64.encodeFromFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Android/data/com.xxx.mobile/cache/signatr.png")).getBytes();

Comment: `signBytes` is your byte array. But how are you sending it to the webservice? Are you calling `signBytes.toString()` and sending it?

Comment: Its sending as it is, uses getBlob()